# How can I count all selected words which are equal to a condition are in a dataframe?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, counter

I have  a have dataframe where I want to count the words in a particular column in the whole dataframe.

Suppose `shape` is a column in dataframe:

```
shape                             color
circle rectangle                  orange
square triangle 
rombus  



square oval                       black
triangle circle

rectangle oval                    white
triangle
```

I want to count in `shape` column how many circles, rectangles, ovals, triangles in dataframe.

Output should be:

```
circle    2
rectangle 2
triangle  3
oval      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
L = ['circle','rectangle','oval','triangle']

s = df['shape'].astype(str).str.split(expand=True).stack()
df = s[s.isin(L)].value_counts().reindex(L, fill_value=0).reset_index()
df.columns = ['vals','counts']
print (df)
        vals  counts
0     circle       2
1  rectangle       2
2       oval       2
3   triangle       3
```

**Explanation**:

1. First [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by whitespace (default separator) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` of words
2. Filter by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) by values in `list`
3. For counting use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)
4. If necessary change ordering or add missing values with `0` add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html)
5. For `DataFrame` from `Series` add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html)

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @tiru - I think need `s = df['shape'].astype(str).str.split(expand=True).stack()` - converting column to `string`s

Comment: @tiru - Can you check `s = df['shape'].astype(str).str.split(expand=True).stack()` ?

Comment: hy jezrael i am geeting the count 0 for all

Answer (score 1):

You can `join` the `'shape'` column with white space and `split` the result.  Pass that to the top level function `pandas.value_counts` and use `reindex` to subset to just the shapes you want to see.

`reindex` has the advantage of returning `nan` if one of your desired shapes doesn't exist in the `'shape'` column.

```
shapes = ['circle','rectangle','oval','triangle']
pd.value_counts(' '.join(df['shape']).split()).reindex(shapes)

circle       2
rectangle    2
oval         2
triangle     3
dtype: int64
```

---

If you expect that you might have missing shapes from your dataset, you can also provide `reindex` a fill value.  Below, I chose to fill it with `0`.

```
shapes = ['circle','rectangle','oval','triangle', 'dodecagon']
pd.value_counts(' '.join(df['shape']).split()).reindex(shapes, fill_value=0)

circle       2
rectangle    2
oval         2
triangle     3
dodecagon    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter` with `itertools.chain` after splitting your strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'shape': ['circle rectangle', 'square triangle',
                             'rombus', 'square oval', 'triangle circle',
                             'rectangle oval', 'triangle']})

from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(df['shape'].str.split()))

print(c)

Counter({'triangle': 3, 'circle': 2, 'rectangle': 2,
         'square': 2, 'oval': 2, 'rombus': 1})
```

This gives a `Counter` object, which is a subclass of `dict`. If you wish to filter your keys, you can do so via a dictionary comprehension:

```
L = {'circle', 'rectangle', 'oval', 'triangle'}

res = {k: v for k, v in c.items() if k in L}

print(res)

{'circle': 2, 'oval': 2, 'rectangle': 2, 'triangle': 3}
```